# How to set the value of root element using JaxB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling

After creating the XML using JAXB, not able to get the value of `@XmlRootElement` in an expected way using `@XmlElement` or `@XmlAttribute`.

### Code 1

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "USER_ID")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class UserD {

    @XmlElement(name = "USER_ID")
    private String userId;
    
    @XmlElement(name = "Name")
    private ArrayList<Name> name;
```

### Output

```
<USER_ID>
            <USER_ID>1</USER_ID>
            <Name></Name>
            <Name></Name>
            <Name></Name>
<USER_ID>
```

### Code 2

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "USER_ID")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class UserD {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "USER_ID")
    private String userId;
    
    @XmlElement(name = "Name")
    private ArrayList<Name> name;
```

### Output 2

```
<USER_ID USER_ID="1">
            <Name></Name>
            <Name></Name>
            <Name></Name>
<USER_ID>
```

### Required Output

```
<USER_ID>1
            <Name></Name>
            <Name></Name>
            <Name></Name>
<USER_ID>
```

Comment: I also could not get it working but the annotations XmlValue and XmlMixed may help you to find a possible solution

Comment: Did you use another approach to get that done?

Answer (score 1):

use the `@XmlMixed` annotation to use the values with xml elements.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "USER_ID")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class UserD {

    @XmlMixed
    private List<String> userId;
    
    @XmlElement(name = "Name")
    private ArrayList<Name> name;

    //getter and setters
}
```

output

```
<USER_ID>1
    <Name></Name>
    <Name></Name>
    <Name></Name>
<USER_ID>
```

Edited

```
Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
```

add the new line character (\n) to end of the value as follows

```
userId.add("1\n")
```

Comment: This works. Thank you! However i getting the <USER_ID> , 1 and first <Name> and </Name> in the same line, not as shown above.

Comment: @SSharma2203 Set the `JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT` property of `Marshaller` to `true`. please refer above modified answer. if it works for you, please accept the answer. :)

Comment: This is already set. It was formatted before using the @XMLMixed but after using that the next tag started to come inline with the root tag.

Comment: @SSharma2203 please refer above modified answer.

Comment: That make sense but i do not think so that this is the right way because then there should be an addition of a TAB char as well then and that would be very dynamic addition.